# Python tesseract OCR to detect arrows

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have some images that have up and down arrows beside some text, and was wondering how I can utilize/optimize tesseract-ocr to detect these symbols. The current output classifies this arrow as a 'T' and some other cases were classified as ' | '. I'm hoping it would return ↑ sweating.

*Update: All up arrows are classified as T it seems, but down arrows are classified differently. (Picture #2)

[image: Example Image]

```
>>> print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image))
T sweating
```

Additionally, down arrows get classified differently.
[image: Example Image],

```
>>> print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image))
4 heart rate
```

And other examples sometimes recognize the down arrow as L or |.

I understand there are various additional languages I can use in the OCR, so my question is are there any languages/configurations I can add to detect arrows?

Comment: Not sure how other add-ons to tesseract will be able to solve this, but if I were to do it, I will try to add some postprocessing to the output of tesseract and manually fix those arrows. E.g., it would be very weird to see a `T` before `sweating`, so that will likely to be an arrow, then I will change that to `[arrow] sweating`.

Comment: Yeah that's an approach I might have to take, I've updated my post, but the issue with that is sometimes different characters are preceded.